# Component not rerendering after state update - no state mutilation

Tags: react-native, redux

My state is updating however the views are not rerendering.

I've looked across many of the answers here and other places on the internet, I'm fairly sure that I'm not mutating my state. 
I've made sure that the state actually changes. I am not sure what's still wrong.

```js
const mapStateToProps = ({ user }: ApplicationState) => ({
  user
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
  setUser: (name: string) => dispatch(setUser(name))
});

export default connect<PropsFromState, PropsFromDispatch>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Login);


export const userReducer: Reducer<UserState> = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER: {
      return { ...state, user: action.payload };
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};


<Provider store={store}>
    <Login />
</Provider>

class Login extends Component<LoginProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
          <Image style={styles.logo} source={require("../../assets/images/logo.png")} />
          <Text style={styles.title}>UniRide</Text>
          <Text style={styles.description}>A social carpooling app for students {this.props.user.user}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <LoginForm setUser={this.props.setUser} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I've checked that the reducer is being called, and the state is changing. However, the page is not rerendering.

Comment: Can you add Login component to the question ?

Comment: @minasameh added